# Struggling with mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php

Can anyone help. I'm trying to shore up my security using mysql_real_escape_string on values passed to PHP for an internal messaging service, but I must be getting the syntax wrong somewhere because the values are not being inserted into the database. I've looked around for tutorials, help etc but struggling to get it right.

The code I'm using is below. The values that haven't been escaped ($email, $from, $time) are being entered correctly, but the other values are just entered blank.

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');

$email=$_SESSION['email'];
$to = $_POST ['touser'];
$toemail = $_POST['touseremail'];
$from = $_SESSION['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$time = time();

$query ="INSERT INTO messages
(to_user, to_email, subject, message, from_user, from_email, daterecord)
VALUES (
'" . mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $to) . "', 
'" . mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $toemail) . "', 
'" . mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $subject) . "', 
'" . mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $message) . "', 
'$from', '$email', '$time')";
$send = $conn -> query($query);

echo "Message sent!";

?>
```

Comment: Shoring up security = stop using `mysql_real_escape_string` and using [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi).

Comment: This function is deprecated. Don't use it.

Comment: [MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) ≠ [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Can you verify that POST contains an actual value? Looking at the values you say are saving are coming from your session, but all the POST values seem to be blank.

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem you're having is that you're mixing up between the `mysql` extension and the `mysqli` extension.

If you're using `mysqli_connect()`, then all the DB functions you use must begin `mysqli_`.

You're using `mysql_real_escape_string`, when the function you actually want is `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

That `i` is very important.

However, if you'll allow me to go beyond the actual problem described, I would recommend moving away from escaped queries, and instead use Parameterised Queries.

Parameterised Queries is a technique that allows you to specify queries like this:

```
SELECT fieldname from talbe WHERE arg = ? AND arg2 = ?
```

and then replace those `?`s with your variables using [`mysqli_bind_param()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

This technique is considered a much better technique than using escape strings.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

check out the function [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

i should also note that the prefered method for escaping strings these days is [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Yes. Use parameterized queries instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of `mysqli_real_escape_string`.
Fix that and it will work better!

Answer (score 0):

Use the function **mysqli_real_escape_string()** instead

Doc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php